# the JAR file tomcat-apr-5.5.23.jar has no source attachment

Tags: java, jar, attachment, unsatisfiedlinkerror

***OBJECTIVE :***

There's an issue I am trying to get through. I have made use of the "tomcat-apr" library in my JAVA program. The build-path for the library is properly configured and class files in this apr project are detectable by the java classes that I have used.

***Situation :***

Now when I try to compile that .java file that uses this apr library generates an exception named :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   org.apache.tomcat.jni.Time.now()J     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jni.Time.now(Native Method)     at
>   com.nxLog.NxLog_t.nxlog_init(NxLog_t.java:88)     at
>   com.mainws.MainWs.main(MainWs.java:35)

Now when I click on the at "*native method*"

> org.apache.tomcat.jni.Time.now(Native Method)

It shows me that the JAR file tomcat-apr-5.5.23.jar has no source attachment. I don't understand when I have the jar file properly build to my project, why this error persists(Expecting this to be a problem related to the jar file configuration...)

Help would be appreciated!!!!

Comment: There are two problems; you're a missing a dependency to a library, causing the UnsatisfiedLinkError. Do you have a dll or .so included in the library? The missing source attachment can be resolved in your IDE by specifying, for your jar dependency, the path to the source (either a zip, jar or folder) associated to your tomcat-apr jar.

Comment: I have already done that. For a particular class in the apr-library, I have attached the source-attachment through add-source button selecting the "External- file" for the path location. But still the problem persists.